# MVVM Light UWP view only showing at design time

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvm-light

I am following a beginner tutorial on MVVM Light and UWP. I have a ViewModel with just a string field that is bound to a TextBlock in main view like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Name="Title"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Title}" />
</Grid>
```

The ViewModelLocator is defined like this in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator xmlns:vm="using:MvvmLight.UWP.ViewModels" x:Key="Locator" />
</Application.Resources>
```

and the ViewModelLocator class looks like this:

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{   
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<StartPageViewModel>();
}

public StartPageViewModel StartPageInstance
{
    get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<StartPageViewModel>(); }
}
```

In the ViewModel I have this in the constructor:

```
Title = "Hello world!";
```

Now, in Design Time, the text appears fine in the designer, but when I run the app, I only get a blank page, and I cannot figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you only declare the `Design Time DataContext`, you should also declare the `Runtime DataContext` in the attributes of your View. For this, add the following:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=StartPageInstance}"
```

After this, you will have something like that:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:design="using:App1.Design"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=StartPageInstance}"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=design:DesignStartPageInstance, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Comment: The only DataContext declared in StartPage.xaml is this one: `DataContext="{Binding StartPageInstance, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`

Comment: As I said in the question, I see the design time text, I don't see it at runtime.

Comment: Is the setter of the Title property notifying ?

Comment: Can you add you xaml code and also the ViewModel code ?